# Getting cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputSplit class not found exception while running hadoop program using cascading framework

Tags: java, hadoop, cascading

Here is my code that connects to hadoop machine and perform set of validation and write on another directory.

```
      public class Main{

            public static void main(String...strings){

        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "root");
        String in1 = "hdfs://myserver/user/root/adnan/inputfile.txt";
        String out = "hdfs://myserver/user/root/cascading/temp2";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        AppProps.setApplicationJarClass(properties, Main.class);
        HadoopFlowConnector flowConnector = new HadoopFlowConnector(properties);

        Tap inTap = new Hfs(new TextDelimited(true, ","), in1);
        Tap outTap = new Hfs(new TextDelimited(true, ","), out);

        Pipe inPipe = new Pipe("in1");  

        Each removeErrors = new Each(inPipe, Fields.ALL, new BigFilter());
        GroupBy group = new GroupBy(removeErrors, getGroupByFields(fieldCols));
        Every mergeGroup = new Every(group, Fields.ALL, new MergeGroupAggregator(fieldCols), Fields.RESULTS);

        FlowDef flowDef = FlowDef.flowDef()
                .addSource(inPipe, inTap)
                .addTailSink(mergeGroup, outTap);

        flowConnector.connect(flowDef).complete();
```

}

My job is getting submitted to hadoop machine. I can check this on job tracker. but job is getting failed and I am getting exception below.

cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputSplit not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputSplit not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:346)
    ... 7 more

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputSplit not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1493)

Note that :
1. I am running this from my windows machine and hadoop is setup on different box. 
2. I am using cloudera distribution for hadoop which is CDH 4.

Comment: @pacoid could you please have a look?

Comment: got the issue. CDH 4.2 has issue with cascading 2.1. So changed to CDH 4.1 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the issue. CDH 4.2 has issue with cascading 2.1. So changed to CDH 4.1 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Properties file is empty so it may be that your configuration for this job is off on the cluster. You must provide the configuration that you are using to `HadoopFlowController`. The information contained in your Hadoop Configuration files found when you call `new Configuration` belongs within your `Properties` object -things like `fs.default.name=file:////` etc. I imagine this is even more so the case when you are running a Cascading job across the "wire".

Comment: CDH 4.2 has issue with cascading 2.1. So Changed that. Thanks for your answer.