# Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1 | Split class cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputSplit not found

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, cascading, scalding

I’m executing a scalding job in Hortonworks distribution (HDP 2.1) and it throws this following issue:

[image]

I tried to locate the cascading jar in Hortonworks but I couldn’t find it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputSplit class not found exception while running hadoop program using cascading framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988091/getting-cascading-tap-hadoop-io-multiinputsplit-class-not-found-exception-while)

Comment: Yes I checked, its for Cloudera. But this issue is in Hortonwork sandbox it cant find the path. I couldn't find it for Hortonwork HDP 2.1. I manually add the jar too but it didnt work.